# How can I get git and copSSH to look in the correct directory for keys?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, msysgit

I just installed copSSH for Windows.  When I boot it up I get a directory  `C:\copSSH\home\Nick\.ssh` which has my pub and private key it.

When I access this directory via a Cygwin bash window using

> ssh user@host

I get happily logged in. However, when I open a git bash window with

> git clone ssh://user@host

it tries to access the keys in `C:\Users\Nick\.ssh`, which gives me a "permission denied" error.  How can I fix git so everything is using `C:\copSSH\home\Nick\.ssh` as the directory?

Comment: Not programming-related, probably belongs on Super User.

Comment: its related to git ? like the other 500 questions on here.

Comment: Just added a potential way to change HOME for each Git bash session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables set by copSSH are not the same than the one found in a git bash Windows. (see also [OpenSSH on Windows](http://wiki.controltier.org/wiki/OpenSSH_on_Windows))

You may need to redefine the $HOME variable to the one used by copSSH. See [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=108) for additional example of HOME redefinition.

By default, `HOME=/c/Users/Nick`.
Try:

```
 export HOME=/c/copSSH/home/Nick
```

---

To make it permanent (each time you open a bash shell), you can try adding this line to your `.bashrc` under `c:\Users\Nick` (`c:\Users\Nick\.bashrc`)

Comment: hi - thanks for the response. how can I also do this for GIT ? i.e. at the moment git is looking for keys in c:\Users\Nick when I want to look for keys in  C:\copSSH\home\Nick\.ssh

Comment: try `export HOME=/c/copSSH/home/Nick` in a git bash shell and check if Git does look for keys in that new directory.

Comment: hi :) thanks again. yes i tried this but it doesnt seem to stay like it permanently ? is there any way to make it stay permanently otherwise everytime I have to try and enter this into bash ?

Comment: i think i love you :) finally, its working and this was the problem the entire time. thanks so much VonC - you are a legend!

Comment: You're welcome... I guess ;) For the legend department, see Jon Skeet (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts ) (although I am pretty sure he would disagree with that qualificatif as well ;) )