# Problems getting git 'server' to work on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I've followed the [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181971/tim)'s [article](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/) (mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows/1503986#1503986) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows)), but - like many others, it seems - I'm stuck when trying do the test clone at the end. I get the `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly` error, even though my $HOME path seems to be right.

Anyone got any pointers to where I might start for debugging this? My git and linux-fu are severely limited...

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433049/git-clone-using-ssh-cant-find-repository/2434967#2434967) to the same question, but it doesn't apply in my case, I don't get any messages about paths.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499279/how-can-i-get-git-and-copssh-to-look-in-the-correct-directory-for-keys/1499801#1499801 has any influence on the issue? (or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154195/git-push-origin-master-invalid-port-number/2154780#2154780)? To debug ssh issue in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461

Comment: @VonC, thanks, I'm working through them. Firstly I realise that the .bashrc hack in section 5.5 of the article I mentioned is wrong, so the `export HOME=` was commented out. But that hasn't solved my problem :(  For what it's worth, I just tried `ssh myuser@10.10.5.74 -p 4837`, which says `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).` So I'm off to brush up on this keys business..

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871273/how-can-i-set-up-a-git-repository-on-windows-and-then-push-to-pull-from-it-on-ma/2871399#2871399 for an interesting technique to debug ssh calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just to formalize my comment:

- [How can I get git and copSSH to look in the correct directory for keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499279/how-can-i-get-git-and-copssh-to-look-in-the-correct-directory-for-keys/1499801#1499801) insists on double-checlin your `$HOME` variable
- [git push origin master , invalid port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154195/git-push-origin-master-invalid-port-number/2154780#2154780) insists on using the right url
- and [Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461) is a compilation of points to check when having ssh connection issues.

Since you mention:

> I just tried

```
 ssh myuser@10.10.5.74 -p 4837
```

> which says

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

it means you need to check how you define your key (probably with a pass-phrase, which might be an issue here)