# How can I set up a git repository on windows, and then push to/pull from it on Mac OSX

Tags: git, cross-platform, ssh

I'm trying to set up a Windows-based web server, but do the development work on Mac OSX.  I installed freeSSHd and msysGit on the Windows server, and set up a repository where I want it. I also have git on my Mac and set up a repo there too.  When I try to clone, pull from, or push to the windows repo via SSH, it gives me an error, "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character" It doesn't matter what I set the remote to in my client (Mac OSX) machine - I can point it to a folder that doesn't exist and it still gives me that error.

I also tried this on a Linux box I have sitting around and it works perfectly, so it's not my Mac.

I have a couple ideas:

1. Maybe freeSSHd isn't behaving correctly ([as suggested here](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/c045ac2fc79e1bfb)) so I could get a different SSH server for Windows - perhaps OpenSSH
2. Perhaps I'm typing the code that combines Mac and Windows file paths incorrectly.  I tried:
   sudo git clone ssh://username@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/C:/Users/[my_username]/[remote_repo_name]/.git [destination]

   and

   sudo git clone ssh://username@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/C:\Users\[my_username]\[remote_repo_name]\.git [destination]

   I'm getting the same error with both of these.

Does anybody know what's going wrong?  Better yet, is there anybody out there that has managed to do what I want to do (push to and pull from a windows repository via SSH)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done that kind of setup (my ssh server is a Solaris10 one), but I have found most ssh error while trying to setup **[gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**.

1. as a prerequisite, gitolite demands that `ssh user@remote git --version` works
2. gitolite uses an interesting ssh configuration property, from the `%HOME%/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

You can not just copy your public key there (ie in "`authorized_keys`"), but you can also reference a script to execute for your ssh command:

```
> more authorized_keys
command="path/to/any/script/you/want" ssh-rsa AAAAB3N;...A_long_key..J6U19Jsf/kuO99XIrNE4ePzHw== username@pc_hostname
```

Meaning any ssh command you will try on that remote `ssh user@remote dir` will actually call that script on the remote (PC) computer.
(if it is a Perl script, it can then call `system(your_command)` to actually execute what you need)

**From that script, you can display and control (and debug) any environment variable that might influence the outcome of the command you are trying to execute through ssh.**
See `.gitolite/src/gl-auth-command` as an example of (Perl) script you can call through ssh (provided it is declare before your public key in your `authorized_keys` file)

Answer (score 0):

Just to suggest something outrageous, what about not using ssh and instead use file sharing. Macs can access Windows shares and git can work of a physical path (which is what a windows share would appear like).